# Changing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

I am trying to change the `innerHTML` of a page twice, more explanation, I am trying to make a single page like app. I'm a newbie. I want to change the inner HTML content of the section after one click then get the `classList` of the changed inner HTML then change it again, but it does not seem to work, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

[image]

my thought process for the code is below

1. select the whole container which is the features container
2. on click, change the container `innerHTML`
3. on click of the changed container `innerHTML`, change the inner HTML again but It doesn't work, it keeps giving me the first `innerHTML` but when i do not display the main container that works, how can i solve this?

```js
const hold = document.querySelector('#features');
const holds = document.querySelector('.features');

let hel;
hold.addEventListener('click', function() {
  holds.innerHTML = `<div class="ddd">h is here </div>`;

  // const self = this;
  hel = document.querySelector('.ddd');
  // console.log(hel.innerText);
  hel.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // holds.style.display = 'none';
    // this.style.display = 'none';
    holds.innerHTML = '<div class="q">mess</div>';
    console.log(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<section id="features" class="features section-hidden">
  <div class="container container-pal1">
    <h2 class="features-description highlight">Features</h2>
    <div class="features-contain">
      <div class="features-text">
        <h3 class="features-header">
          We are here to provide you with the
          <span class="features-highlight">Best</span> services
        </h3>
        <p class="features-title">
          Everything you need in a modern bank and more, get on our waiting list today by clicking the button below
        </p>
        <a href="" class="hero-cta-1 features-button">View our services <img src="./assets/arrow-right.svg" alt="" />
                </a>
      </div>
      <div class="features-props">
        <div class="features-list">
          <div class="features-item">
            <img src="./assets/fast-delivery.svg" alt="" />
            <h5>Swift Delivery </h5>
            <p>No late transfer, get it instantly</p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-item">
            <img src="./assets/0-fees.svg" alt="" />
            <h5>$0 Fee's</h5>
            <p>No fees on your account like the other banks</p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-item">
            <img src="./assets//0-interest.svg" alt="" />
            <h5>Interest &percnt;</h5>
            <p>
              Interest when applying for loans depends on your agreement from the bank
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-item">
            <img src="./assets/no-credit-check.svg" alt="" />
            <h5>Credit Card</h5>
            <p>Credit cards available at your demand</p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-item">
            <img src="./assets/chat-support.svg" alt="" />
            <h5>Chat Support</h5>
            <p>Chat with a company representative anytime</p>
          </div>
          <div class="features-item">
            <img src="./assets/fixed-payment-option.svg" alt="" />
            <h5>Fixed Payment Option</h5>
            <p>Payment Options will be provided</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you want to make a single page app, I'd recommend that you use on of the (many) platforms that already do this, for example, [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) or [Angular](https://angular.io/)

Comment: @Liam Don't forget about the much better and faster [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/)

Comment: Better is subjective :) I'm not really intending to list all the frameworks, there are many... [Ember](https://emberjs.com/) anyone...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i already added some html

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan my main build is a single page app, where i have a login page, then when I login the login [age disappears then the main content comes in after then on the main content I can do somethings with some elements on it, its just something very basic no need for a back end and all so I'm confused on how to go about it. I do not plan on making it a MPA just ones single page app,

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan how can i go about this build, I don't mind jumping on a call to get a little bit of clarity, I do not know reactjs yet

Comment: @Ogunleye Hard to tell what is your end desire. The simplest way would be to have both the HTML elements you want to swap and simply toggle a class that does display:none;  on one of the elements. Otherwise you could load dynamically using AJAX the desired content.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan do you mind jumping on a call maybe i can give further clarity on what I want to achieve

Comment: Do a research on Google: JS load content dynamically using AJAX - Single page application etc. to get an idea.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan okay no problem, i added an image with the question with what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Ogunleye you said you'll have a login. If you have no server - forget about the login page. That's not secure to keep plaintext credentials in the code served to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example how to switch elements that already exist in the DOM.
Use a `data-*` attribute to reference the desired ID element to show.
Use classList.toggle to switch the Elements.

```js
const ELS_pages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");
const ELS_buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-page]");
const goToPage = (id) => {
  ELS_pages.forEach(EL => EL.classList.toggle("u-none", EL.id !== id));
};

ELS_buttons.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", () => {
  goToPage(EL.dataset.page);
}));
```

```css
nav {display: flex;} nav a {color: #00f; padding: 5px 10px; cursor: pointer; }
/* Utility classes */
.u-none {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="page" id="page-login">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <button type="button" data-page="page-main">ENTER</button>
</div>

<div class="page u-none" id="page-main">
   <nav>
     <a data-page="page-settings">User Settings</a>
     <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
   </nav>
   <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>
</div>

<div class="page u-none" id="page-settings">
   <nav>
     <a data-page="page-main">Back to Main</a>
     <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
   </nav>
   <h1>SETTINGS PAGE</h1>
</div>
```

This is basic, and does not change the URI address in the browser. To achieve that some more code should be added to handle such case.

Answer (score -1):

Try keeping a flag(if there are only two different data you want to show) and based on the flag show data or a counter

```
const hold = document.querySelector('#features');
let count = 0;

hold.addEventListener('click', function() {
  switch (count){
    case 0:
      holds.innerHTML = `<div class="ddd">h is here </div>`;
    case 1:
      holds.innerHTML = `<div class="ddd">now some other is here </div>`
  };
});
```

and please provide more info for the remaining answer

Answer (score -1):

Simply run your second innerHTML code after the next repaint using `requestAnimationFrame` and it will work.

```
const hold = document.querySelector("#features");
const holds = document.querySelector(".features");

let hel;
hold.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  holds.innerHTML = `<div class="ddd">h is here </div>`;

  // const self = this;
  hel = document.querySelector(".ddd");
  // console.log(hel.innerText);
  hel.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // holds.style.display = 'none';
    // this.style.display = 'none';
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      holds.innerHTML = '<div class="q">mess</div>';
    });

    console.log(this);
  });
});
```

if you need further information about why it's happening read [this article](https://www.macarthur.me/posts/when-dom-updates-appear-to-be-asynchronous).

Comment: What is wrong with OP's code for suggesting requestAnimationFrame ?

Comment: try it. its not working for the second innerHTML update.

Comment: OK, but your suggestion is not good. The sole reason it does not work is because the click events propagation. Never use click handlers inside other click handlers. The inner click should be moved outside of the parent `hold.addEventListener` - and `evt.target.closest("selector")` should be used to determine the dynamic clicked element - since we're talking about dynamic creation of Elements.